# Copying a single line in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3.0.  When I double click on a line to highlight and copy the contents of a line, it is also copying the first space in the next line as well. I included a screenshot of it. In the screenshot I wanted to copy the second line, but it automatically is taking the first space in the third line.

I can of course, drag my mouse over the text to highlight it, and then copy, but that's not what I want to do. I simply want to select a single line with a double click.

How do I fix this? Is there a setting to disable it from copying that first space in the next line?

[image]

Comment: you should accept the answer. the correct answer. I have triend @Odatnurd solution, and it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

What you're actually seeing is not it selecting the space at the start of the next line, but the newline at the end of the line that you selected.

That is to say, when you double click on a line to select it, use `Selection > Expand Selection to Line` or even just press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to copy the current line when there is no selection (assuming `copy_with_empty_selection` is turned on), the contents of the line includes the character that terminates it as well, since that's arguably part of the line.

There's not a setting that controls this behaviour as far as I'm aware.

Probably the most expedient solution would be to create a file named `copy_line.sublime-macro` in your `User` package (use `Preferences > Browse Preferences` if you're not sure where that is) with the following contents:

```json
[
    { "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "line"} },
    { "command": "split_selection_into_lines" },
    { "command": "copy" }
]
```

Then add a key binding to execute it when you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> but don't have anything selected:

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+c"],
    "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/copy_line.sublime-macro"},
    "context": [
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": "true", "match_all": true}
    ]
},
```

Now when you press the copy key with nothing selected, the whole line is selected (which includes the newline), split into lines (which don't have the newline) and then copied to the clipboard.

This works even if you have multiple cursors, although they all have to have no selection for it to trigger.

Comment: thank you so much. it works on mine. sublime 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the cursor to the line you want to copy and Ctrl-C (Cmd-C on Mac). Do not select the line,  just stay on it. Then paste it anywhere you want to paste, and it will insert a new line before the one your cursor is on,  with the previously copied text.

Is it what you want or do I miss something?

Comment: thanks superkeci, that's a neat feature that I didn't know about but it still appears take it one space too far when I paste it. When I copy text into a database cell I still have to hit backspace once

Comment: Oh, you're right. So the only option I see is hitting Ctrl-L first and then Ctrl-Shift-L on a line to select it without EOL character.